# Consulta de arreglos en C#

Tags: c#, array

No puedo sacar la información fuera de los ciclos `for`.

Adjunto **código**:

```
char[] resto, tresprimeras=null;
string[] arregloletras = { "Margarita", "Sara", "Karina", "Mario" };

Console.Write("\n Primeras 3 letras de los nombres. \n");

for (int i = 0; i < arregloletras.Length; i++)
{
    tresprimeras = arregloletras[i].ToCharArray(0,3);
    Console.WriteLine(tresprimeras);

}

Console.Write("\n Resto de letras de los nombres. \n");

for (int a = 0; a < arregloletras.Length; a++)
{
    int rest = arregloletras[a].Length;
    resto = arregloletras[a].ToCharArray(3,rest-3);
    Console.WriteLine(resto);
}
```

Necesito almacenar 3 arreglos

**1.** arreglo1 las 3 primeras letras de todos los nombres.

**2.** arreglo2 el resto de las letras de los nombres.

**3.** arreglo3 concatenar los 2 arreglos anteriores para volverlos nombres completos

Quiero sacar tres primeras y resto para unirlas en un arreglo string para concatenarlas y volver a unirlas, porfa si me hechan una manito, gracias.

Comment: `resto y tresprimeras` no deberian ser un arreglo de string en vez de char?

Comment: lo intente pero no puedo sacar las primeras 3 letras ni el resto sin que sean tipo char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui la respuesta:

Adiciona este using:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Aquí el código:

```
    List<string> resto = new List<string>();
    List<string> tresprimeras = new List<string>();
    string[] arregloletras = { "Margarita", "Sara", "Karina", "Mario" };

    Console.Write("\n Primeras 3 letras de los nombres. \n");

    for (int i = 0; i < arregloletras.Length; i++)
    {
         tresprimeras.Add(arregloletras[i].Substring(0, 3));
         Console.WriteLine(tresprimeras[i]);
    }

    Console.Write("\n Resto de letras de los nombres. \n");

    for (int a = 0; a < arregloletras.Length; a++)
    {
         int rest = arregloletras[a].Length;
         resto.Add(arregloletras[a].Substring(3, rest - 3));
         Console.WriteLine(resto[a]);
    }

    Console.Write("\n Unir todas las letras de los nombres. \n");

    for (int a = 0; a < arregloletras.Length; a++)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(tresprimeras[a]+resto[a]);
    }
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: uuuu filete jtaborga me funciono sorry soy novato con suerte me enseñaron a colocar los arreglos y con eso nos dieron una guia y que nos la arreglaramos solos. solo tuve que colocarle los [i] y a la otra [a] y me funco  en los writeline.

Comment: No te olvides de marcar la respuesta que consideras correcta. Para que pueda ser utilizada por la comunidad.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que debes hacer es declarar arreglos de `string` y no de `char`. De esta forma podrás usar el método `Substring`.

El código que te dejo hace todo en un `for` si necesitas hacer los cortes y la concatenación en bucles separados, solo agregas los bucles necesarios.

> He cambiado los nombres de las variables para darle un nombre más significativo o descriptivo.

```
string[] arregloNombreOriginal = { "Margarita", "Sara", "Karina", "Mario" };

string[] arregloTresPrimeras = new string[arregloNombreOriginal.Length];
string[] arregloResto = new string[arregloNombreOriginal.Length];
string[] arregloNombreCompletro = new string[arregloNombreOriginal.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < arregloNombreOriginal.Length; i++)
{
    // obteniendo las 3 primeras letras
    arregloTresPrimeras[i] = arregloNombreOriginal[i].Substring(0, 3);

    // obteniendo el resto.
    arregloResto[i] = arregloNombreOriginal[i].Substring(3);

    // concatenando
    arregloNombreCompletro[i] = arregloTresPrimeras[i] + arregloResto[i];

    Console.WriteLine("Para el nombre " + arregloNombreOriginal[i]);
    Console.WriteLine("Las tres primeras letras son: " + arregloTresPrimeras[i]);
    Console.WriteLine("Y el resto es: " + arregloResto[i]);
    Console.WriteLine("La concatenacion: " + arregloNombreCompletro[i]);
    Console.WriteLine("\n");
}
```

Si te fijas al Substring `arregloNombreOriginal[i].Substring(0, 3);` se le pasa dos parámetros: el `0` indicando que comience de la posición inicial de la cadena y un `3` indicando hasta donde debe cortar la cadena.

El segundo Substring `arregloNombreOriginal[i].Substring(3);` solo se le pasa un parámetro, y es el `3`, el cual indica que a partir de esa posición hasta el final de la cadena se cortara.

> [Substring](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8): Recupera una subcadena de la instancia. La subcadena comienza en una posición de carácter especificada y tiene una longitud especificada.

Comment: Gracias orlando

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener las 3 primeras letras de cada item del array podrias usar el `Substring()` sobre el string

```
List<string> tresprimeras= new List<string>();
string[] arregloletras = { "Margarita", "Sara", "Karina", "Mario" };

Console.WriteLine("\n Primeras 3 letras de los nombres.");

foreach (var item in arregloletras)
{
    tresprimeras.Add(item.Substring(0, 3));
}

foreach (var item in tresprimeras)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```